# How to include ffmpeg in my jni folder and build .so file?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I have successfully build `ffmpeg`.

After that I have added the include.h files in my jni folder.

[jni folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iefG.png)

My ffmpeg-jni.c file :

[ffmpeg-jni.c](https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme/blob/master/app/src/main/jni/ffmpeg-jni.c)

When I build ndk . It comes like this.

[error in ndk-build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5So7A.png)

After adding common.h . It comes with another one error.

[in command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTQ9A.png)

[scroll 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMMCb.png)

[scroll 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfryn.png)

How can I solve this and build .so file?
These are my `ffmpeg` build files
[image]
[image]

Comment: whats your minsdkversion?

Comment: My Minimum  SDK  version  19

Comment: use https://github.com/PratikVekariya4445/FFmpegAndroid

Comment: How to use this for .so file build https://github.com/PratikVekariya4445/FFmpegAndroid

Comment: Aren't you reinventing the weel? See https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg if you want to use ffmpeg libraries in-process, or https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android if you want to run ffpmeg executable.

Comment: Alex cohn How can I use this for build this .so file? I can't understand what you are saying.